# OleDbException was unhandled by user code - Unspecified error

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

The following error keeps popping up randomly when my program is running.
Quite new to this so i'm not sure how to go about catching this...
Did a quick search alrd but nothing seems to help.

The following is part of my code:

```
protected DBBase(string tableName, string primary_key)
{
    string s = Application.StartupPath + "\\alliancedb.accdb";
    conn = new OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0}", s));
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        conn.Open();
        dataset = new DataSet();
        //query statement
        string sqlStatement = String.Format("Select * from {0} order by {1} ASC", tableName, primary_key);
        //run sql
        DBadpt = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStatement, conn);
        oOrderDetailsCmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(DBadpt);
        DBadpt.Fill(dataset);
        dbTab = dataset.Tables[0];
        dbTab.TableName = this.tableName = tableName;

        rows = dbTab.Rows;
    }
    else if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Open();
        dataset = new DataSet();
        //query statement
        string sqlStatement = String.Format("Select * from {0} order by {1} ASC", tableName, primary_key);
        //run sql
        DBadpt = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStatement, conn);
        oOrderDetailsCmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(DBadpt);
        DBadpt.Fill(dataset);
        dbTab = dataset.Tables[0];
        dbTab.TableName = this.tableName = tableName;

        rows = dbTab.Rows;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't leave your connections open.  Always open them, get your data, then close them immediately.  The `using` block is usually the cleanest method that closes the object for you.

Also, if any of your tables or fields are keywords or have a space in them, you would have to put them in [brackets]:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0}", s))) {
  conn.Open();
  string sqlStatement = String.Format("Select * from [{0}] order by [{1}] ASC", tableName, primary_key);
  // etc..
}
```